# spring boot response Entity

Tags: json, spring

While getting the all products from spring boot It converts my key name to lowercase instead of returning with original value.

```
[{"pname":"Mobile","pquantity":52,"pid":1,"pprice":2000}]
```

And my entity follow camel case.

I want to return with camel case, how to do that in Spring Boot?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add a subset of your code, the minimal reproducer for your problem. It could be the controller definition, or the DTO declaration.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you are using `spring-boot-starter-web` what use `jackson` for data serialization/deserialization and you can specify the field name of object in the response just adding next ones annotation.

**on Field level:**

```
@JsonProperty("pName")
private String pName;
```

**on Class level:**

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.LowerCamelCaseStrategy.class)
public class Classz
```

For more information/ details i really suggest to have a look here [jackson annotations](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/package-summary.html)

Comment: `@JsonProperty("pName")` is optionnal, better use the right strategy that you mention. And it should be the default so OP must have a configuration problem.